# How to call a method from another class using Java

Tags: java

How can I call a method when I press a button from a separate class?

For example, when the click event fires on the `Save` button I want to call the `setRDF` method from the other class named `GenerateRDF`

This is my code:

```
public class PersonalInfo extends JPanel {
    private void initialize() {
        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // call the `setRDF` method here
            }
        }); 
   }
}

public class GenerateRDF extends Object {
      public void setRDF() {
        String personURI    = "http://localhost/amitkumar";
        String givenName    = "Amit";
        String familyName   = "Kumar";
        String fullName     = givenName+familyName;

        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

        Resource node = model.createResource(personURI)
                 .addProperty(VCARD.FN, fullName)
                 .addProperty(VCARD.N,
                              model.createResource()
                                   .addProperty(VCARD.Given, givenName)
                                   .addProperty(VCARD.Family, familyName));
        model.write(System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: `extends Object` is not necessary, it's implicit. All classes extend `Object` by default in java. And if `Object` is a class you created, you should rename it. Creating classes with the same name as other default java classes is the best way to confuse other developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a new `GenerateRDF` object and call the method on that. For example:

```
public class PersonalInfo extends JPanel {
    private void initialize() {
        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                GenerateRDF generator = new GenerateRDF();
                generator.setRDF();
            }
        }); 
   }
}
```

Side note: you don't need to write `extends Ojbect`; everything extends `Object` by default.